# Как правильно указать AppIndex?

Tags: java, android

Все было так, я подключил `logIn` кнопку гугл и она отлично работала.

Потом я работал над проектом и решил все запустить и проверить и вот когда дошел до активити с авторизацией вылетел с ошибкой

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.camera2basic/com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization.AuthorizationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppIndex: The URI host must match the package name and follow the format (android-app:////[host_path]). Provided URI: android-app://com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization/http/host/path
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjt.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzju.start(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization.AuthorizationActivity.onStart(AuthorizationActivity.java:374)

Вроде ничего, что касалось гугл регистрации не трогал. Согласно описанию ошибки то неверно введен формат `AppIndex`, но я не могу понять от чего он зависит, как проверить как правильно? Я ничего не менял и работало а сейчас не правильно... Странно...

Подскажите что не так?

Вот часть кода в которой ошибка

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Authorization Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization/http/host/path")
    );

    ---> AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction); <---
}
```

Comment: В итоге я удалил эту строку в которой вылетала ошибка и все работает... Не пойму зачем она вообще нужна была, так как делал по примеру... Странно... Но удалил и вроде все работает, посмотрим где еще отвалиться

Answer (score 1):

Судя по логам вы пытаетесь выдать строку

> android-app://com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization/http/host/path

за валидный путь, коий, судя по всему у вас должен быть

```
android-app://com.example.android.camera2basic.authorization
```

т.е. `/http/host/path`, похоже, лишние

Comment: ничего не поменялось... Я дополнил часть вопроса

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, в вашем коде не видно, чтобы вы пытались заменить `Uri.parse("http://host/path")` на null и убрать "/http/host/path" из последнего URI

Comment: В итоге я удалил эту строку в которой вылетала ошибка и все работает... Не пойму зачем она вообще нужна была, так как делал по примеру... Странно... Но удалил и вроде все работает, посмотрим где еще отвалиться

Comment: Напишите это в ответ